# How to implement SignOut request NextAuth with Django REST API?

Tags: django, authentication, next.js, django-rest-framework, next-auth

I am trying to create a frontend on the next-js for my Django REST API. I use Next Auth for frontend auth and token auth for backend API. For login, I used API, for example, **[www.mysite.com/login](http://www.mysite.com/login)** and I got token and user data, so for logout, I used API endpoint example **[www.mysite.com/logout](http://www.mysite.com/logout)** is needed to pass the token in headers. So how to implement logout?

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import api from "../baseaxios"


const SIGN_IN_HANDLERS = {
  "credentials": async (user, account, profile, email, credentials) => {
    return true;
  },
};
const SIGN_IN_PROVIDERS = Object.keys(SIGN_IN_HANDLERS);

const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
          name: 'Credentials',
          credentials: {
            username: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "Email" },
            password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
          },
          async authorize(credentials, req) {

            const res = await api.post("/login", {
              body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
              headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
            })
            
            const user = await res.json()
      
            if (res.ok && user) {
              return user
            }
            return null
          }
        })
      ],
 pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({user, account, profile, email, credentials}) {
      if (!SIGN_IN_PROVIDERS.includes(account.provider)) return false;
      return SIGN_IN_HANDLERS[account.provider](
        user, account, profile, email, credentials
      );
    },
    async jwt({user, token, account}) {
      // If `user` and `account` are set that means it is a login event
      if (user && account) {
        let backendResponse = account.provider === "credentials" ? user : account.meta;
        token["user"] = backendResponse.user;
        token["token"] = backendResponse.token;
        return token;
      }
      return token;
    },

    async session({token}) {
      return token;
    },

})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

I tried to do it function like this to logout on back and on front at the same time:

```
import {signOut, useSession} from "next-auth/react";
const {data: session } = useSession();
const logout = () => { await axios.post('/logout', {
    Authentication: 'Token' + session?.token ,);
    signOut();
};
```

But is it a good way?